# Java app deployment and installer parameters

Tags: jar, javapackager

I am using javapackager for making installer from .jar. I need to give some params to my installer(splash screen icon, remove version from app name etc), that can't be given directly by javapackager. Instead javapackager has an paramfile option, but I don't know how to use it, and what structure will it have?? Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

it is a java properties file. You can look in https://github.com/Debian/openjfx for the parameter you want to override and then set it in the properties file.